# can I get public/index.html to work alongside another root_path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, public-html

I just implemented a new homepage using public/index.html which I read that it overrides a lot of the routes.

I originally had `root to: static_pages#home` and in my `static_pages\home.html.erb` view if a user was logged in, they saw the logged in homepage and the anonymous visitor (public/index.html) homepage if not logged in.

After implementing public/index.html, I created a new route for logged in users and made previous root_path redirects to home_path

```
get '/home' => 'static_pages#home', :as => :home
```

However, I would like to use `http://localhost:3000` as the homepage for both logged in and visitor homepages. Is this possible? How can I have visitors see the current public/index.html which works good right now, but not have to use `http://localhost:3000/home` after login? I want `http://localhost:3000` after login as well.

Thanks

Comment: You would need to code that or look for a filter that someone has made that changes what is included depending on the logged in cookie status.

Answer (score 1):

`public/index.html` is served by webserver before Rails, so you need another solution.

Instead you can move `public/index.html` into `app/views/static_pages/index.html` and edit your controller as follows:

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home 
    if signed_in?
      # current content of #home action
    else
      render :index, :layout => false
    end
  end
end
```

or even more clean way

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :show_index_page, :only => :home

  def home 
    # the same
  end

private
  def show_index_page
    render :index, :layout => false unless signed_in?
  end
end
```

Comment: If I went back to my original home.html.erb method where I have `<% if signed_in? %>` and `<% else %>`, is there a code or something that I can use to make everything below `<% else %>` to have no existing formats / free from everything else? It appears that when I copy and paste what is currently inside public/index.html into there, the formatting is all off so I'm wondering if I can encase the code around something

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a simple HomeController which render the right view for corresponding user.

You must have two erb view files for anonymous and signed in user.

Comment: how should the HomeController be like to render the right view? Is it just `class StaticPagesController` `def home`
    `if signed_in?` something here `else` something here `end`?